# See the SQL commands generated by EntityFramework: Cast exception

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137712/sql-tracing-linq-to-entities#138109), I'm doing the following to get the SQL enerated by Entity Framework 5.0

```
var query = from s in db.ClassesDetails
            where s.ClassSet == "SetOne"
            orderby s.ClassNum
            select s.ClassNum;
var objectQuery = (System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query; // <= problem!
var sql = objectQuery.ToTraceString();
```

However on the second line I get the following exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Int16]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.
```

Did something change since those SO answers were posted? What do I need to do to get the queries as strings? We're running against Azure SQL so can't run the usual SQL profiler tools :(

Answer (score 1):

ObjectQuery is created when you are using ObjectContext. When you are using DbContext it uses and creates DbQuery. Also, note that this is actually not a `DbQuery` but `DbQuery<T>`. I believe that to display SQL when having DbQueries you can just do `.ToString()` on the DbQuery instance so no cast should be required. Note that parameter values will not be displayed though. Parameter values were added to the output very recently in EF6 - if you need this you can try the latest nightly build from http://entityframework.codeplex.com